# Displaying data in Listbox in VB

Tags: vb.net

I want display data from database in Listbox...Here is my code, It is not working. In Listbox it is displaying as Object[,].Array.....What can i do...

Dim DBCONSRT, QRYSTR As String

```
    Dim strSQL As String

    Dim DBCON, myConn, myCommand, rs As Object

    Dim NoOfRecords As Long

    rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    Const DB_CONNECT_STRING = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=cpa5k;Data Source=NP1;DSN=NP1;UID=user;PASSWORD=pass;SDSN=Default;HST=ibslnpb1.sysplex.homedepot.com;PRT=4101;Initial Catalog=QA1MM;"

    myConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    myCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    myConn.Open(DB_CONNECT_STRING)
    myCommand.ActiveConnection = myConn
    strSQL = "select * from QA1MM.STRSK_OH with ur;"
    rs.Open(strSQL, myConn)
    ListBox1.Items.Add(rs.GetRows(2))
    myConn.Close()
```

Comment: After this i want to display the whole table in GridView..How can i do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetRows method is used to retrieve a specified number of rows from a Recordset and to fill an array with the resulting data. so the solution would be to first add the items to an array and then iterate to add the data to the listbox.

```
rs.Open(strSQL, myConn)
    While Not rs.EOF

        ListBox1.Items.Add(rs(0).value)

        rs.MoveNext()
    End While
myConn.Close()
```

For datagrid:

```
Set DataGrid1.DataSource = rs
DataGrid1.Refresh
```

Comment: How to do that?...i dont know

Comment: Which column do you want to display in the list box?

Comment: In Visual Basic 2005 only DataGridView is there..If i give DataGridView1.DataSource = rs it is not working..Wat to do...